# Install compiled python's libraries to virtual environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line, pip, ubuntu-14.04

I'd like to install already compiled mathematical libraries under virtual environment located here: `.env/bin`, but with using

```
SYS_INSTALL="apt-get install -y"
$SYS_INSTALL python-numpy
$SYS_INSTALL python-scipy
$SYS_INSTALL python-matplotlib
$SYS_INSTALL python-pandas
$SYS_INSTALL python-sklearn
```

Is there any chance for using `apt-get install`, but install under `.env/bin` ?

Comment: create your `virualenv` with `virtualenv --system-site-packages`

Comment: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide.html#the-system-site-packages-option